# SQL Server row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, row-number

I have a problem to create a custom `rownumber` with an alias column. Here are some sample data:

Table `question`:

```
id   title   
--   --------    
1     xx
2     xxx
```

..

Table `customerLikeQuestion`:

```
Id   QuestionId CustomerId
---------------------------
1       20          xx
2       100         xx 
xx
```

Query:

```
SELECT  q.Id,
        (SELECT     COUNT(*) 
         FROM          dbo.CustomerLikeQuestion
         WHERE      (QuestionId = q.Id)) AS LikeCount
FROM dbo.Question AS q
ORDER BY likecount DESC
```

The previous query shows:

```
 id    LikeCount
2136    6
2138    5
2150    5
```

Now I'd like to put a `rownumber` to count an incremental order of a row. I tried the following query:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT Id,
           (SELECT     COUNT(*) AS Expr1
            FROM          dbo.CustomerLikeQuestion
            WHERE      (QuestionId = q.Id)) AS LikeCount, 
            row_number() over (order by likecount) as RowNum
FROM         dbo.Question AS q
ORDER BY likecount DESC
```

But it gives me the following error:

> *invalid column Likecount.*

I do know that `Over()` cannot work with alias, but how can I get around this problem, either with CTE or subquery, I have not yet come up with any idea. please help.

The right result should be like this:

```
id  likecount, rownum
----------------------    
xx     6        1
xx     5        2 
xx     4        3
..     0        xx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead

```
;WITH LiksCounts
AS
(
    SELECT Id,
           (SELECT     COUNT(*) AS Expr1
            FROM          dbo.CustomerLikeQuestion
            WHERE      (QuestionId = q.Id)) AS LikeCount
    FROM         dbo.Question AS q
     GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT TOP(100) *, row_number() over (order by likecount) as RowNum
fROM LiksCounts
ORDER BY RowNum ASC
```

### [Live DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82456/sql-server-row-number)

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, but i need the result with  rownum increasing 1 2 3 4 5, but still hold likecount   top down like 6 5 3 1